# dialogflow webhook fulfilment code fails

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate Alexa with Dialogflow and using dialogflow to fulfil intent request. For static intent response i am able to get response correctly but when i am trying to integrate webhook for fullfillment, i am getting below exception dialogflow :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
>       at V2Agent.processRequest_ (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:108:86)
>       at new WebhookClient (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:193:17)
>       at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:26:18)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:684:7
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:668:9
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Below is the code i am using for the fulfillment webhook :

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function orcacall () {
      response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
      response.send(JSON.stringify({'speech':'myMessage','displayText':'myMessage','data':[],'contextOut':[]}));


  }
let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Orca', orcacall);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet you have tried. Just the stacktrace is not enough

Comment: Apologies, added the code

Comment: What is the version of library you are using. As there is a fix up for similar issue https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/pull/51 . Try updating to the latest version of dialogflow-fulillment .

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu, updating to latest version of dialogflow-fullfilment worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, only after posting my answer I found out that you've already got your answer from the comments.

Your `orcaCall` function needs an `agent` argument. Change it to this:

```
function orcacall (agent) {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  response.send(JSON.stringify({'speech':'myMessage','displayText':'myMessage','data':[],'contextOut':[]}));  }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late to post

Your `orcacall()` function needs an argument `agent` So Change it to

```
console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function orcacall (agent) { //Here agent is added
      response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
```

This argument is useful in using parameters and also posting the responses.